# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 210858: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to use pandas to open a CSV file: `train = pd.read_csv('train_lending.csv')`,

I get: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 210858: invalid start byte`.

Answer (score -1):

```
train = pd.read_csv('train_lending.csv', encoding='ISO-8859–1')
```

Comment: Same as the answer in the duplicate.